# Deploying component using Services on OCM10gr3

Tags: java, oracle-ucm

I am trying to deploy the component on OCM 10gr3 using RIDC and the services i am using are

```
 GET_COMPONENT_INSTALL_FORM
 GET_MANIFEST_INFO
```

Following is the code that I am working with

```
idcClient = manager.createClient("http://localhost/idc/idcplg");
idcClient.getConfig().setProperty("http.library","apache4");
userPasswordContext = new IdcContext("username","password");

DataBinder dataBinder = idcClient.createBinder ();
dataBinder.putLocal("IdcService", "GET_COMPONENT_INSTALL_FORM");
dataBinder.putLocal("IDC_Id","idc");
dataBinder.putLocal("UserTempAuth","d://TestComponent.zip");
dataBinder.putLocal("File","ComponentZipFile");
dataBinder.putLocal("Submit","  Install  ");

dataBinder.putLocal("IdcService","GET_MANIFEST_INFO");
dataBinder.putLocal("ComponentName","TestComponent");
dataBinder.putLocal("location","TestComponent/TestComponent.hda");

ServiceResponse response = idcClient.sendRequest (userPasswordContext, dataBinder);
DataBinder binderResult = response.getResponseAsBinder();
```

But i am still facing problems in deploying the component using this code, while debugging too, i did not faced any exception or errors.
So Can anyone guide me regarding what i should do next.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.
The first problem is that you trying to run two services in one call.
The second problem is that you aren't running the correct services. This last statement is hard for me to verify, since you are using a version that has been replaced a long time ago, but judging from the current version, your first service seems to be right. The name of the second service is UPLOAD_NEW_COMPONENT in 12c. The output from the first service call takes a few parameters from the first response - this might be irrelevant in your case though.